# How to find which templates a GPO are using?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

With a Windows 2012 R2 AD domain, we have a Central Store for group policy templates.  Over time, a number of unnecessary templates were added to this store (most of them are not used) and it has grown over the years.  Is it possible to determine which templates are being used by a GPO (or which templates are not being used)?  I can't find anything and haven't been able to figure it out, but we need to remove the ones that are not being used.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most aren't used?  How many do you have?  A vanilla 2012 R2 policy definitions folder has 178 files.

Comment: We have 470 of them.  Using a Central Store on the domain where they are kept.

Comment: Powershell may be a solution. Check out the Get-GPOReport cmdlet. The resultant XML may contain needed information under ExtensionData\Extension node.

Comment: This is hackish, but if you have a limited number of GPOs, a more blunt solution is to simply remove everything that's not default, then look through the settings tab in GPMC for each GPO. This won't affect the policies from functioning, but they will no longer populate descriptions or be editable from the GUI.